# Java : メソッドの変数について

Tags: java

calcTriangleAreaメソッド内の変数area(4行目)とcalcCircleAreaメソッド内の変数area(11行目)は
変数名が同一なだけで別物だということはわかるのですが、同じにする理由はあるのでしょうか。
異なるメソッドなので、少し違う変数名に変えた方が分かりやすいと思ったのですが。
実際の仕事で作る際はどういった感じなのでしょうか。

参考:
スッキリわかるJava入門 第3版,222ページ

> ```
> public static double calcTriangleArea(double bottom,double height) {
>     double area = bottom * height / 2;
>
>     return area; }
>
> public static double calcCircleArea(double radius) {
>     final double PI = 3.14;
>     double area = radius * radius * PI;
>
>     return area; } public static void main(String[] args) {
>     double triangleArea = calcTriangleArea(10.0, 5.0);
>     double circleArea = calcCircleArea(5.0);
>
>     System.out.println(triangleArea);
>     System.out.println(circleArea); }
> ```

Comment: 「下のコードはある問題の模範解答のコードです。」とありますが、引用元を質問に追記しましょう。

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございます。次回から気を付けます。

Comment: 質問は後から編集可能ですので今からでも追記可能ですよ。

Comment: 編集ありがとうございます。とりあえず、私自身でも編集しましたが、もう少し詳しく記載した方がよろしいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

私ならareaのままにします。※実務では、どのような命名にするかを規約で定めている場合がありますので、絶対的なものではありません。

calcTriangleAreaが三角形の面積を計算することが明らかなので、ローカルな変数名を単に面積(area)とするのは自然だと思います。
例えば変数名をtriangleArea(三角形の面積)とすると、三角形であることを強調しているため、人によって「三角形以外の面積も関係があるのでは？」と余計なことを考えてしまうかも知れません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
回答者様のご意見の通りにやってみます。

Comment: この回答で疑問点が解決した場合、回答の左に側にあるチェックマークをクリックし、この回答を承認いただけますでしょうか？システム的に、この質問が解決済みであることを示すことができます。

Comment: まだ使い始めたばかりでシステムを理解していませんでした。教えて頂きありがとうございます。